# How to consume this WebService in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I am developing a application to consume the web service, how to consume the following web-service? http method or ksoap2? I tried Ksoap2, seems can not extract this web service properly, anybody can help on this? thanks in advance.

Here is the wsdl: https://integrator-ut.vegaconnection.com/Authentication.svc?wsdl

Is that the NAME_SPACE is: "http://tempuri.org/" method is CreateToken? and the SOAP_ACTION is http://tempuri.org/IAuthentication/CreateToken?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use KSOAP, you can use httpUrlconnection and InputStream

```
        HttpURLConnection my_httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://integrator-ut.vegaconnection.com/Authentication.svc?wsdl").openConnection();
        my_httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        my_httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        my_httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        my_httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");



       OutputStream my_outPutStream = this.my_httpConnection.getOutputStream();
       Writer my_writer = new OutputStreamWriter(my_outPutStream);
       my_writer.write(YOUR_REQUEST); //YOUR_REQUEST is a String
       my_writer.flush();
       my_writer.close();           

       BufferedReader my_bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.my_httpConnection.getInputStream()));
        char[] buffer = new char[10000];
        int nbCharRead=0;
        try
        {
            while((nbCharRead = my_bufferReader.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1)
            {
                 /* Your treatement : saving on a file/arraylist/etc

            }
        }
```

You have to make the string **YOUR_REQUEST** based on the values ​​you want to recover

It look's like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" ... >
<soapenv:Header/>      
<soapenv:Body>
...
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

please post ur web service method code.

```
**Sample web service method**

public String Login(string userName, string pwd)  throws SoapFault   
{           

    String data = "";

    String serviceUrl =  "https://abc.com/xyz.svc";

    String serviceNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";

    String soapAction = "http://abc.org/IAuthentication/CreateToken";

    String type_of_soap = "CreateToken";   

    try
    {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace, type_of_soap);
            //txtUserName,txtPassword these two are edit text ref variables but these are decalred before of this.
            Request.addProperty("userName", txtUserName.getText().toString());    
            Request.addProperty("password", txtPassword.getText().toString()); 


        System.out.println("GetRestaurantDetails:"+Request.toString()); 

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        try
        {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(serviceUrl);
            androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Webservice calling error ->"+e.toString());
        }

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        data = response.toString();
        System.out.println("GetRestaurantDetails:"+response.toString());
        tv.setText(data );//this text view can be declared before this.

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Soap Method Error ->"+e.toString());    
    }        
    return data;
}
```

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public string Login(string userName, string pwd)
    {
        string msg = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Authentication.Authentication auth = new Authentication.Authentication();
            Authentication.LoginToken login = auth.CreateToken(userName, pwd);
            msg = "Login Successful";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }

Comment: which tool u are using for web service method(like ksaop)?

Comment: i call ksoap service from android mobile application

Comment: But u are not calling the ws method in ur code?what are the requested attributes?

Comment: i added sample web service method. please refer that.

Comment: SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();                                tv.setText(result.toString());                                        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
}
     
  });

Comment: please add entire web service method in ur post not in comments.

Comment: previously i add that wsdl file in .net web services and deploy in IIS...using that URL in android it returns exception ..but when ever i used directly that wsdl url it didn't any return value....

Comment: can you send ur serviceUrl,serviceNamespace,soapAction, type_of_soap of ur ws method and what are the requested parameters?

Comment: ur url's are not opening that's why i am asking?